# PHP JSON_DECODE ARRAY

Tags: php, arrays, json, decode, data-conversion

I am using following code to decode json array

```
$json_contacts ='[{"addr_name":"1","addr_phone":"010-1111-1111"},{"addr_name":"2","addr_phone":"010-1111-1112"},{"addr_name":"3","addr_phone":"010-1111-1113"},{"addr_name":"4","addr_phone":"010-1111-1114"}]';

$contact = json_decode($json_contacts, true);
echo $json_contacts;
echo "\n";
echo $contact;
echo "\nTHE END";
```

I am getting following result

```
[{"addr_name":"1","addr_phone":"010-1111-1111"},{"addr_name":"2","addr_phone":"010-1111-1112"},{"addr_name":"3","addr_phone":"010-1111-1113"},{"addr_name":"4","addr_phone":"010-1111-1114"}]

THE END
```

Why is my JSON_DECODE not decoding the array properly?

Comment: turn on error reporting on php - http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: tried but no errors...

Comment: I have checked your code and shows warning in line "echo $contact;" , changed into "print_r($contact);" and it prints all array values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$json_contacts ='[{"addr_name":"1","addr_phone":"010-1111-1111"},{"addr_name":"2","addr_phone":"010-1111-1112"},{"addr_name":"3","addr_phone":"010-1111-1113"},{"addr_name":"4","addr_phone":"010-1111-1114"}]';

$contact = json_decode($json_contacts, true);
echo $json_contacts;
echo "\n";
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $contact);

echo '</pre>';
echo "\nTHE END";
```

---

Because you echo your previous `$json_contacts` and you didn't turn on PHP notice. You cannot echo `$contact` because it's an array.

Comment: I am not that much of newbie... Ofcourse the script is written with in <?php ?>. Or else it will not have shown the result as I mentioned above.

Comment: @HamDongKyun i know you're not newbie. please just copy all of that. and do print_r($contact); not echo $contact.